# adding tab on facebook page with custom label for add app and passing some data with it

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating an app for making fanpage. User can create their page design on my website and on publish button click that app should be added to the page as a tab along with the designed made. I have the page ID and App Id.. Please suggest some way by which I can directly add the tab . Also when I use the

http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=app_api_key&page=page_id,

it shows add app button can I change the label of that button..

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this programagically by using the following calls :

[See here for acquiring page tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) ( scroll down to "Page Login")

```
$page_token = 'XXX' // This is the page token
$app_id = '123456789' // This is the app that you want to install
$tab_title = 'My Tab Name';

// The following lines of code will install the tab app onto the page.
$install_tab_call = "/{$page_id}/tabs?app_id={$app_id}&access_token={$page_token}";
$facebook->api($install_tab_call,'POST');

// The following lines of code will update the tab app's name on the page.              
$change_tab_call = "/{$page_id}/tabs/app_{$app_id}?custom_name={$tab_title}&access_token={$page_token}";
$facebook->api($change_tab_call,'POST');
```

Because you are using these commands to execute your actions, you can use any UI design that fits your needs - no need to customize Facebook UI.  Just place your own elements on the page that call the script above.  I recommend using an AJAX call.

Additionally, you can check out all the other settings you can manipulate for your pages tabs in the documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

**Be aware that you'll need the `manage_pages` permissions to perform any action dealing with page settings.**